# Regex Pattern required for a specific string case

Tags: java, regex

In the below string I'm supposed to read the value from `` ` `` (opening single quote - ASCII value 96) until `└`. I couldn't figure out how to come up with a regex for this case - errors due to alphanumeric and numeric conditions. Please HELP!

[image: nonworking string]

Actual string:

```
str="00└9a00└9g00└9`000└9a00└9e000└9a00└9`000└9a00└9e000└9a00└9`000└9a00└9e000└9a00└9`000└9a";
```

Data to be read: between `` ` `` and `└`.

Comment: Please update your question with the actual string you are trying to parse.

Comment: updated with the actual string cheers

Comment: That first character is not a single-quote (or apostrophe), it's a grave accent.  I fixed the formatting so you can see it more clearly. The other one appears to be `U+2514`, one of the box-drawing characters.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work? The captured string should be what you want.

```
Pattern p = pattern.compile("'([^└]*)└"); // ('[^└]*└) if you want the ' and └ too
```

Comment: Those are probably not square brackets in his string. They are some funky characters that the GUI does not know how to display.

Comment: I figured as much, but I didn't know what else to use to represent what he wanted to match.

Comment: those are not square brackets sorry. When I did a printing on screen, i received this └. It would be great if the pattern is with java syntax. Pattern p = pattern.compile(regex);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
Pattern.compile("`(\\p{Print}++)")
```

and capture $1?